# Jenkins- Unable to execute shell command

Tags: macos, jenkins

I am very new to **Jenkins** and getting an issue which I think is related to path setting:

I have a simple **Java** program which I am able to run using Terminal following below commands:

```
cd /Users/john/IdeaProjects/HelloWorld
javac HelloWorld.java
java HelloWorld
```

I have put same commands in Jenkins project- Execute shell window and getting error as below, please guide me:

Console output:

> Running as SYSTEM Building in workspace
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/HelloWorld [HelloWorld] $ /bin/sh
>   -xe /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/jenkins4399115153751264307.sh
>   + cd /Users/swyam/IdeaProjects/HelloWorld
>   + javac HelloWorld.java HelloWorld.java:1: error: error while writing HelloWorld: /Users/swyam/IdeaProjects/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.class
>   public class HelloWorld {
>          ^ 1 error Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE

Comment: That looks like a mangled compiler error.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too. Probably not Jenkins related.

Answer (score 0):

shebang :

#!/bin/sh

use shebang in first line of shell command  then call your java code.
Hope this helps if it works then please mark it as tick